# Taking the classical limit $v\ll c$ in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to understand some of my class notes. My professor reached 2 equations:

$$m_0c^2 \frac{d\gamma}{dt}=\textbf{F} \cdot \textbf v\tag{1}$$ 
and
$$m_0\frac{d\gamma \textbf v}{dt}=\textbf F\tag{2}$$
where the bold letters are 4-vectors. He then wrote that when considering the limit case $v\ll c$, $\gamma \approx 1+{v^2}/{2c^2}$, such that eq. (1) reduces to
$$\frac{dE_{\text{kinetic}}}{dt}=W$$
That is, the change in classical kinetic energy is equal to the work done on the system. So far so good. But then he wrote that eq.(2) reduces to 
$$F=m_0 \frac{dv^i}{dt}$$ 
for $i=1, 2, 3$, which is Newton's 2nd law.

As far as I can see, eq.(2) reduces to Newton's law only when considering $\gamma \approx 1$. It wouldn't reduce to Newton's law if we had made the same approximation used in eq.(1), namely that $\gamma \approx 1+ {v^2}/{2c^2}$.

Does this mean that the formula that relates the change in kinetic energy to the work done on the system is accurate in a broader range of speeds than Newton's second law? Because that's accurate for low speeds up to 2nd order in the Taylor expansion of $\gamma$, while Newton's second law is only accurate for low speed up to the 1st order in the Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small parameter in question ought to be $\beta=v/c$. If you expand $\gamma\approx 1+ 1/2 \beta^2 - 1/8 \beta^4$, you find 
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma &\approx 1+ 1/2 \beta^2 +\mathcal{O}(\beta^4)\\
c^2\gamma &\approx c^2 + 1/2 v^2 -1/8 v^2\beta^2 + \mathcal{O}(\beta^4)
\end{align}
$$

Neglecting $\beta^2$ and higher powers, we find that
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma &\approx 1\\
c^2\gamma &\approx c^2 + 1/2 v^2
\end{align}
$$
The approximations in your example  turn out to be the same order in $\beta$. One isn't more accurate than the other.

Comment: I might come back to this, I wrote it quickly and now unsure